# rails js best practices

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I insert js code directly into view.

post.html.erb:

```
<%=@post.text%>
<script>
  alert("Hello!")
</script>
```

Maybe it's not the best way. Tell me the best solution to put js code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with your solution though there is a helper that you can use that will automatically wrap it in a CDATA section so it might be safer on older browsers:

```
<%= javascript_tag do %>
  alert("Hello!")
<% end %>
```